# Why istream::getline() returns so many times (with nothing)

Tags: c++, getline

I am trying to read a poorly formatted text file, and maybe I'm going about this the wrong way, but based on the getline documentation it sounded like it would pull values until the values weren't a delimiter value (' ', in my case):

> "If the delimiter is found, it is extracted and discarded, i.e. it is
>   not stored and the next input operation will begin after it. If you
>   don't want this character to be extracted, you can use member get
>   instead."

But for some reason it returns nothing many times. See lines 604-607, all those commas in my output are returns of getline. Could someone tell me why it is returning blanks 6 times before it comes to the value? The text file only contains one space before the value. Thanks in advance. :)

Relevant screenshot: http://j.drhu.me/2011-09-07_1317.png

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
void CMuscleModel::LoadOpParams()
{
int i, j;

ifstream param("params.txt", ios::in);
        if (param.is_open())
        {
            stringstream iss, isn;
            string line, word;

            i=0; j=0;
            while (getline(param,line))
            {
                isn.clear();
                isn << line;
                if(i>27){
                    while (getline(isn,word,' ')) {
                        //LGma[i][j]=atof(word.c_str());
                        if(word == "SM"){
                            getline(param,line);
                            cout << line << endl << endl;

                            isn.clear(); isn << line;

                            getline(isn,word,' ');

                            int junk=0;
                            while (atof(word.c_str())==0){
                                junk++;
                                getline(isn,word,' ');
                            }

                            cout << atof(word.c_str()) << ", " << junk << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "ST"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "BFL"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "BFS"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "MG"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "LG"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "RF"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "VM"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "VL"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        if(word == "VI"){
                            cout << word << endl;
                        }
                        j++;
                    }
                }
                j=0; i++;
                isn.clear();
            }
        }
        param.close();
}
```

Ah, sorry for not including code.

Comment: Please include a minimal compilable code example that exhibits the problem you are having _in the body of your question_.

Comment: What is `isn`?  I'm suspicious that you write to it `isn << line;` and then the next line of code reads from it `getline(isn,word,' ');`

Comment: Also, is it possible that the input line before (SM) was followed by a tab that got converted to five spaces?

Comment: Can you reduce your posted program to a complete, minimal, compileable example, including a short input, and the expected and actual output? For an explanation of why that is important, see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the output text file I was reading from had trailing spaces and they were just being put into the stream so I was really confused about what was going on. I simply used .str("") at the end of each line to reset my current stream and things worked out marvelously. Thanks for all the help guys.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using space as a delimiter anytime it's encountered getline will return with whatever there was upto the delimiter. If the file had 5 spaces in a row before any other characters for example you'd now have to call getline 6 times.

Perhaps use the default newline character instead `'\n'`?

**Edit:** Didn't see code before. Perhaps restructure your code to read lines and then use `find` in conjunction with `substr` on each line to search for your keywords? Would be simpler code and less looping. There is no reason to read from the file only to output to a stringstream which you then read from.

Comment: That is why I'm confused. There was only 1 space before the value I was looking to snag.

Comment: errors, end of file, etc can also cause extraction to end and `getline` to return.

Answer (score 1):

Bi-directional I/O with `std::stringstream` is really ambiguous.  I recommand that you use it a little differently.

```
ifstream param("params.txt", ios::in);
if (param.is_open())
{
    stringstream iss;
    string line, word;
    i=0; j=0;
    while (getline(param,line))
    {
        istringstream isn(line);
        // ...
    }
}
```

This creates a fresh string stream with clean state and contains the contents of the line read from the file each time.  If you really want to re-use the instance for reading tokens on multiple lines, I recommand you use the `.str(line)` syntax rather than `.clear()` and `operator<<`.

If you want to clear the whitespace at the beginning of each line, you can use the [`std::ws` manipulator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/ws/):

```
istringstream isn(line);
isn >> ws;
// ...
```